# Using mapreduce how to search the words of a particular file in all other files present in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have multiple files which contain the name, id and skill sets of the employees and another file "skills.txt" which contains list of some particular skills. I am trying to write a java mapreduce program to find out the employees who have the skills mentioned in skills.txt.

E.g. Suppose there are 3 employee files as below: 
**emp1.txt-** 
Name: Tom 
EmpId: 001 
Skills: C++, Java, SQL

**emp2.txt-**
Name: Jerry 
EmpId: 002 
Skills: C++, PHP, SQL

**emp3.txt-** 
Name: Jack
EmpId: 002 
Skills: Java, PHP

**Skills.txt-**
PHP
SQL

Then my result should be as below.
PHP Jerry-002 ; Jack-003
SQL Tom-001 ; Jerry-002

All these four files are in my HDFS. 
I am very new to hadoop and mapreduce.. I have already struggled a lot for this, but not getting any proper logic to do it. I am able to write the program, if there is only one skill and I get the skill needed to search as an argument to mapreduce program. But I am unable to do when there are multiple skills are to be searched and the skills are there in a file format along with other employee files.

Comment: Is it a must criterion to use map reduce here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will be to add the skills.txt file to your DistributedCache. In your mapper you use your setup() function to read the file then:

```
Path[] uris = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
String skillsfile = uris[0].toString(); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(patternsFile));
```

During the job setup you will have to add the file to the distributed cache:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(skillsFile), job.getConfiguration());
```

I hope this will get you on your way..

Comment: Thank you irW for your time and effort. I will try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your skills list is this short you could just pass it to your mapper through **Configuration**, read it back in your mapper and match it with the input. Why would you create a separate file for just 2 entries? IMHO, this will be more convenient. Something like this :

**In your driver -**

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("skillList", "PHP,MYSQL");
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

**In your mapper -**

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
String skillList = conf.get("skillList");
//Split skillList and do the rest
```

But, if the list is going to really big, you are better off using Dist. Cache.